# html img tag with error - FF display issue

Tags: html, css, image

I'm using Html img tag as following :

```
<img src="url_to_some_pic" alt="alternative error message"
    width="300" height="300">
</img>
```

In case where of broken url Chrome & IE Display this error message as expected inside
the image origin dimensaion BUT FF not .

what happens in FF is that FF display the error message but 
in one line and not inside the image area (300 x 300).

Anyone knows how to fixes this issue ?

I'm guessing that css will be the solution but how ?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: So you want some message to pop when a user moves a mouse on top of it?

Comment: The `alt` attribute specifies an alternate text to be used (displayed or spoken) when the image is not displayed, not an error message. What is the original problem that you expect `alt` to solve?

Comment: I wanted to display error message in case the url is broken and the image can't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser is handling alt it's own way and there is no consistent way to format it.
I would consider placing your image into the container.

At least this way alt will always be placed at top left.

http://jsfiddle.net/WjKxN/1/

HTML:

```
<div id='image'>
    <img src="url_to_some_pic" alt="alternative error message" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: The suggested solution will create a border even when the image is present. If you use a background color on the `div` instead, the image display will not be affected unless the images has some transparency.

Comment: @JohnSmith2, what exactly did you try?

Comment: I wrapped the the img tag with div as you suggested.
forgot to mention that I'm using iterator which create those images.

Comment: @JohnSmith2: Without you showing us a clear example, we wont be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have a markup error. The img tag is an auto-closing one. You should use it like that instead :

```
<img src="url_to_some_pic" alt="alternative error message"
width="300" height="300" />
```

That should fix your problem. But also, maybe it is good to know that a better and more standard way to add width and height to your image would be with CSS, like that :

```
<img src="url_to_some_pic" alt="alternative error message"
style="height: 300px; width: 300px;" />
```

Comment: Would be nice to know why there is a -1 on this.

Comment: The added slash has no impact on the problem.

Comment: It's not about the added slash, but about the removal of the </img> that is plain wrong.